# Multidimensional arrays in Kotlin Android

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin

Here's my array of arrays

**string.xml**

```
<array name="answers">
    <item>
        <string-array name="answer0">
            <item>answer0</item>
            <item>nswr0</item>
            <item>answerzero</item>
        </string-array>
    </item>
    <item>
        <string-array name="answer1">
            <item>answer1</item>
            <item>nswr1</item>
            <item>answerone</item>
        </string-array>
    </item>
    <item>
        <string-array name="answer2">
            <item>answer2</item>
            <item>nswr2</item>
            <item>answertwo</item>
        </string-array>
    </item> </array>
```

And how do I make a check so that at least one element is in this array?
I want each question to have 3 correct answers. For a user typing - **answer0 or nswr0** - he will be notified that the answer is correct in the first and second case.
I tried this method. But if I use an index, I get an [error](https://i.ibb.co/vkZBpzW/1.png).

**checkArray()**

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener {
    val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_text).text
    val array = resources.getStringArray(R.array.answers)

    if (array[here i want to use an index].any { it == editText.toString() }) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "In array", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not in array", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to use multidimensional arrays in Android resources
As a workaround let's make a projection of a 2d array onto 1d

```
<string-array name="answers">
    <item>[[answer0]]</item>
    <item>answer0</item>
    <item>nswr0</item>
    <item>answerzero</item>
    <item>[[answer1]]</item>
    <item>answer1</item>
    <item>nswr1</item>
    <item>answerone</item>
    <item>[[answer2]]</item>
    <item>answer2</item>
    <item>nswr2</item>
    <item>answertwo</item>
</string-array>
```

The names of arrays are bracketed `[[<name of array>]]`
Then it's easy to parse and separate them
Of course, you can use your own divider